# IE: UpdatePanel + LinkButton + Text does not Trigger async PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I am running into an issue in IE9/10 where I have an UpdatePanel consisting of a LinkButton with `Text="Click Here<i></i>"` (see code below) and when the user clicks on the  portion of the LinkButton the async postback does not trigger. Does anyone know why this happens or has anyone run into this issue before? Is there a way to resolve this?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="pnlDoSomething" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lbClickMe" OnClick="lbClickMe_Click" Text="Click Here<i></i>" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbClickMe" EventName="Click" />
         </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </div>
```

The `<i></i>` is used to slide in an icon. If the user clicks on the text ("Click Me"), the async postback triggers and my code-behind runs. If the user clicks on the `<i></i>` image, no async postback occurs.

Comment: Where is control `lbAddRemoveAutoTrader`?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I updated the code. I forgot to change out that control name.

Comment: It's not necessary to add `Triggers` when update will be triggered by child control since by default update is fired by childs. I don't think this could cause problems but I'd remove it and give it a try.